# Division Rule : Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Division Rule states that - There are n/d ways to do a task if it can be done using a procedure that can be carried out in n ways, and for every way w, exactly d of the n ways correspond
to way w.

I've understood the definition of the division rule in combinatorics to some extent but I am not able to apply it on the following problem :

Kenneth Rosen - 7th Edition - Basics of Counting - 45th question

How many ways are there to seat six people around a circular table where two seatings are considered the same when everyone has the same two neighbors without regard to whether they are right or left neighbors?

Answer = 60

The solution is explained as follows -

If we imagine the places at the table as fixed, then there are 6 · 5 · 4 · 3 · 2 · 1 = 6! ways to seat the six people-choose one of the six people for seat #1, choose one of the five remaining people for seat #2, and so on. However, this overcounts by a factor of 6, corresponding to rotating the table (which does not change a person's neighbors), and by a factor of 2, because any given
arrangement is the "same" under the stated rules as the arrangement that reverses the order of the people (changing clockwise to counterclockwise). Therefore the answer is 6!/(6 · 2) = 60. 
An alternative way to look at it is as follows. Without loss of generality, have person A take a seat. Choose his two neighbors in one of 5 · 4/2 = 10 ways and have them sit on either side of him. Now place the other three people in one of the 3! ways possible in the remaining seats. The number of ways, then, is 10 · 6 = 60.

Can someone please explain how to solve this problem using division rule ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define what the division rule is, I'm getting an answer of 504 instead!

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I had posted the wrong question. My apologies. I've updated my query. Please check now.

Comment: The divison rule approach would go $5!/2=60$ ways. Fix one person, the others go around $5!$ ways, divide by two because reflecting the configuration yields the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @ParclyTaxel I got confused with the approach followed in the solution.